# Keyframes transfer from FK to IK bones

Tags: keyframes

I am having a character  animation with simple hand movements.
The character is rigged with rigify and in hand movement animation, the keyframes are inserted on FK hands. Here, I would like to transfer the keyframes made of FK hands to the IK hands. Please help.

Comment: care to share your blend file https://blend-exchange.com or share some screenshots?

Comment: I am attaching the Google drive link of the blend file. You can find that all keyframes are inserted on FK hands & legs. I want those keyframes to be inserted on IK bones. Link: https://drive.google.com/file/d/1oN0iUiikkkqh0i0u5gJm8UO9OV2qQrzI/view?usp=sharing